# sqoop query is giving error for the Import command

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to transfer 35 GB table from aws rds postgres to hive but when I try to full table it take much time and after long time execution get stop. so I decide to load incremental way.

schema:All are in varchar except mentioned below.

- twoway_id
- twoway_seq  =>int
- guid
- twoway_section_cd
- transmit_host_nm
- receipt_host_nm
- service_id
- msg_id
- msg_no
- vin_id
- twoway_dt
- status_result_cd
- company_cd
- limit_count_yn
- response_status_cd
- create_user_id
- create_app_id
- create_tmsmp =>timestamp
- update_user_id
- update_app_id
- update_tmsmp =>timestamp

kshsjsjsj   320393682   IN K    02  TMU ISS CMM GPI 14  0   20201800230936  FAIL    02  Y   500 ISS ISS 2020-12-02 17:36:36.447 ISS ISS 2020-12-02 17:36:36.462
326403236

```
sqoop query: This query is working perfectly for full table load.

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k"\
 --query 'SELECT * FROM db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012 where 1=1 AND $CONDITIONS'\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --hive-import --hive-table db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012\
 --hive-drop-import-delims\
 --hive-overwrite --hs2-url jdbc:hive2://hivehostname:10000/default;
```

```
tried but not working

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k"\
 --query 'SELECT * FROM db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012 where create_tmsmp like '2020-12-01%' AND $CONDITIONS'\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --hive-import --hive-table db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012\
 --hive-drop-import-delims\
 --hive-overwrite --hs2-url jdbc:hive2://hivehostname:10000/default;

Error:
21/12/29 16:02:43 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 
ERROR: operator does not exist: integer % boolean
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

```
This is also not working

sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k \
 --table `db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202112`\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --where "create_tmsmp < 2020-12-04 04:51:26.150"\ 
 --append
```

```
Also help me on incremental load query. I am also facing syntax error issue.

Incremental import arguments:

Argument    Description
--check-column (col)    Specifies the column to be examined when determining which rows to import.
--incremental (mode)    Specifies how Sqoop determines which rows are new. Legal values for mode include append and lastmodified.
--last-value (value)    Specifies the maximum value of the check column from the previous import.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you are passing `--where` need to be changed like below. You need to use single quotes around strings.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k \
 --table `db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202112`\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --where " create_tmsmp < TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-12-04 04:51:26','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' )"\
```

or

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k"\
 --query "SELECT * FROM db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012 where create_tmsmp < TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-12-04 04:51:26','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AND \\\$CONDITIONS"\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --hive-import --hive-table db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202012\
```

Pls change position of \$CONDITIONS if above doesn't work.

Now you can implement **Incremental sqoop** like below.

1. NEW ROWS : you can use `--incremental append` to append new records. identify a column which  can be used to determine brand new record - like primary key. And also calculate max() of that column in hive(i assumed it to be 1000). Load those data using below sqoop.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k \
 --table `db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202112`\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --check-column pk_col \
--incremental append \
--last-value 1000
```

So this above Sqoop will append any row where pk_col > 10000 from postgres.

2. EXISTING ROWS : Similarly you may want to bring modified rows from source. Then use below SQL. You need to first calculate max() of create_tmsmp and then use it in below statement(i assumed max to be 2020-12-04 04:51:26).

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/db_core_k \
 --table `db_core.service_twoway_ifo_202112`\
 --m 1 --target-dir "/user/hive/warehouse/db_core.db/service_twoway_ifo_202112"\
 --username test --password test001 \
 --check-column create_tmsmp \
--incremental lastmodified \
--last-value "'2020-12-04 04:51:26'"
```